# Loading string representation of dictionaries with single quotes in their values as dictionary literals

Tags: python, json, python-3.x, dictionary

I'm trying to parse some logs that among other things display some python dictionaries and extract the values from them.

An example input would be something like `{'name' : 'D'Artagnan'}`
ast lib's literal_eval() gives an invalid syntax error while json.loads() requires all quotes to be double quotes, but if I get to replace all quotes with double quotes it will become `{"name" : "D"Artagnan"}` which is invalid as the value of name is now D and it then expects a comma delimiter to take the next key-value pair.

The types of names are not always formatted in the same way (for example <single_quote> like in D'Artagnan but they sometimes have space or nothing between or after them (for example "'t Something").

I looked around here but while others have been having similar issues, I didn't find something that can help me figure this out. The only workaround that I found so far was to handle them on a case-by-case base, writing a try-except clause that would handle JSONDecodeErrors by writing the offensive line down in a log file and then reading the file(as a human) and creating if-elif cases of the type

```py
if "D'Artagnan" in line:
    line = line.replace("'","\'")
```

which solves the issue but is tedious, creates unnecessary overhead and skips values until I fix it which I feel is very wrong. Any help would be welcome!

Thanks!

Answer (score 2, accepted):

In the event that you need to escape those `'` characters, I think the `re` module might help.

```
import ast
import re

data = "{'name' : 'D'Artagnan'}"
data = re.sub(r"(\w)'(\w)", r"\1\\'\2", data)
print(ast.literal_eval(data))
```

Should give you a dictionary:

```
{'name': "D'Artagnan"}
```

Comment: Hey, thanks a lot! I'm sorry for the late reply, I read it but didn't understand the regex part as I've only used regular expressions for some project in uni 3 years ago and don't remember the syntax, so I wanted to understand it, test it and see if it works for my case! 
I'll come back to you as soon as I've tested it out in the next couple of days! Thanks again!